# Boot screen missing

Tags: windows, ubuntu, partitioning, boot

I have a few partitions in my hard drive:

- Windows 7 system
- Kubuntu
- Others

My Windows crashed and I reinstalled it in the same partition. However I am now unable to access the boot menu to boot into Kubuntu - it automatically boots into Windows.

What can I do?

If it's of any use, this is what the computer Disk Management screen looks like:

[image]

Comment: You've probably overwritten the MBR, so it needs to be fixed to detect the other systems.

Comment: Thanks for leading me to some direction. Im trying to mount the partitions and install grub.. Is that the correct thing to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sound as though the reinstall of Windows overwrote the boot loader. This is a common thing with Windows and Linux co-habitating. Just go back and reinstall GRUB and this should sort it out for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot .. Working perfectly now. Used boot-repair to reinstall grub.

Comment: @Mellkor  Then accept please. :)